# onHandleIntent method is not called on IntentService

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app which starts a service when the device is connected to the internet.
the problem is that the onHandleIntent method is not called in my IntentService subclass.
can somebody please explain for me why??

Below is my IntentService subclass:

```
public class RefreshService extends IntentService {
static final String TAG = "REFRESH_SERVICE";

public RefreshService() {
    super("RefreshService");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(RefreshService.this, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(RefreshService.this, "onHandleIntent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(RefreshService.this, "onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

And below is my BroadcastReceiver subclass:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
    Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //
    int statusNumber = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    if (statusNumber == 1 || statusNumber == 2) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, RefreshService.class));
    }
}
}
```

And this is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapplication">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <service android:name=".RefreshService" />

    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

And here is my NetworkUtil class:

```
public class NetworkUtil {

public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return TYPE_WIFI;

        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            return TYPE_MOBILE;
    }
    return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
}

public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
    int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    String status = null;
    if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
        status = "Wifi enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        status = "Mobile data enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        status = "Not connected to Internet";
    }
    return status;
}
}
```

The sequence of displayed toast messages are:
(when connected to the internet with wifi)

Not connected to Internet
  Wifi enabled
  onCreate
  onDestroy

my question is that why onHandleIntent message is not displayed???

Comment: You can't `Toast` directly from the `onHandleIntent()`, as it runs on a separate thread. Remove that, and just use your log print.

Comment: thanks @mike-m you are right. but why by running on a separate thread the toast message is not working???

Comment: `Toast`s are UI functions, so they have to be issued from the main thread. If you really, _really_ want to issue a `Toast` from `onHandleIntent()`, there's a way to do it, but if you're just using it for debugging, stick with the log print.